# error: no matching function for call to'arch::newsucc(). I tried everything,but nothing worked

Tags: c++, c++11

I tried to call the function print and it worked.The function newsucc the only one who had this problem. I tried to rename it, and made the function at class national like this
virtual void newsucc(int students, int succ) { };
and a lot of things but nothing worked
the code about an exam at our country that could national exam, we should use class and inheritance in c++
the base class is national
the child class are arch and IT

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class National {
protected:
    string name;
    int students;
    int succ;

public:
    National()
    {
        name = "";
        students = 0;
        succ = 0;
    }
    National(string ex, int s, int su)
    {

        name = ex;
        students = s;
        succ = su;
    }
    National(National&N ) {

        this->name = N.name;
        this->students = N.students;
        this->succ = N.succ;

    }
    void print()
    {
        cout << "The results of the National Exam" << endl;

    }

    virtual void newsucc() { };

    ~National()
    {
        cout << "The End" << endl;
    }
};
class arch : public National {
public:
    arch(int _students, int _succ) :National("architecture engineering", _students, _succ)
    {
    }

    ~arch()
    {

    }
    void print() {

        cout << "The National Exam's result of the architecture engineering is" << endl;

    }
     void newsucc(int _students,int _succ)
    {
        cout << "The number of the Successful students" <<  (_students*_succ)/100 << endl;

    }
};
class IT : public National
{
public:
    IT (int _students, int _succ) : National("IT engineering", _students, _succ)
    {
    }

    ~IT()
    {

    }
    void print() {

        cout << "The National Exam's result of the IT engineering" << endl;

    }
    void newsucc(int _students,int _succ)
    {
        cout << "The number of the Successful students" <<  (_students*_succ)/100 << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{



    cout << "-----------------------------------" << endl;

    arch obj2 (300,65);
    obj2.newsucc();


    cout << "-----------------------------------" << endl;
    IT obj3 (500,40);
    obj3.newsucc();

}
```

Comment: You have two kinds of `newsucc` member functions here: Once which do not take any argument and once which require two arguments. Why do you have both of these? Should `newsucc` not either always expect two arguments or never expect one? I don't know what `newsucc` is intended to do. Does it need any arguments for the action it is supposed to perform or not? Instead of taking `_students` and `_succ` as parameter, should it maybe just refer to the classes' `students` and `succ` members instead?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them, for example by showing us a [mcve] (with emphasis on the *minimal* part) and the actual errors you get.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The OP provided an MRE. See [demo](https://onlinegdb.com/4XL2jk_o0) that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Also take this as a lesson to always use the `override` special identifier when overriding virtual functions (as in `void newsucc(int _students,int _succ) override { ... }`). If you attempt to override using a different function signature the compiler will give you an error.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure if the duplicates are correct, because it's hard to say what OP wants to do and which `newsucc` is correct.

Comment: @AnoopRana [It could be reduced to less than 20 lines](https://godbolt.org/z/31nbhqKsb).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yup OP probably wasn't probably aware of that in which case your comment will be helpul to them.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you're right. I read about override, and I solved the problem. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The **problem** is that the `arch::newsucc` that you provided inside the derived class `arch`(and others) is not overriding the virtual from base `National::newsucc()` but instead it **hides** it.

So when you wrote:

```
obj2.newsuck();
```

the compiler sees that there is a `newsucc` available inside the derived class and stops the searching(aka lookup). That is, it never looks into the base class. But since the `newsucc` inside the derived class takes `2` arguments and since you've called `newsucc` with `0` arguments you get the mentioned error.

---

You can solve this either by making the derived class' `newsucc` to be taking no parameters or by making the base class' version taking 2 ints or by just simply passing 2 arguments when calling `newsucc` as shown below. Also note that you can make use of the `override` keyword to explictly see that whether you're actually overriding a virtual from base or not.

Here we remove the 2 parameters from the derived classes and no change is made in the derived class.

```
class arch : public National {
public:
    arch(int _students, int _succ) :National("architecture engineering", _students, _succ)
    {
    }

    ~arch()
    {

    }
    void print() {

        cout << "The National Exam's result of the architecture engineering is" << endl;

    }
//----------------v-->removed parameters 
     void newsucc( ) override //override used here
    {
        cout << "The number of the Successful students" <<  (_students*_succ)/100 << endl;

    }
};
class IT : public National
{
public:
    IT (int _students, int _succ) : National("IT engineering", _students, _succ)
    {
    }

    ~IT()
    {

    }
    void print() {

        cout << "The National Exam's result of the IT engineering" << endl;

    }
//---------------v-->removed parameters 
    void newsucc( ) override //override used here 
    {
        cout << "The number of the Successful students" <<  (_students*_succ)/100 << endl;
    }
};
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/nabRxyBUA)

Note again that there are other method to solve this like just calling `newsucc` with `2` arguments or making `National::newsucc` to have 2 parameters.

Comment: you're right. I did what you said and it worked  and for who is asking, the newsucc function is to calculate the number of success students, they give is the number of all students and the percentage. thanks for all of you